# In Linux-workqueue work routine: create new work-item and wait for it to finish

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I use a workqueue to defer work. Since I know beforehand how many work-items I want to be processed, I initialize an atomic variable with that number. I set my process current state to to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`, submit all the work and then send the process to sleep with `schedule()`. In each work routine at the end the atomic variable is decreased and tested. If the last work-item has been completed the process is woken up.

Is there a better way to do this?

And my actual question: if i want to defer work from within a work routine itself, can I achieve the same thing? For the process I pass `current` to the work routine, which is then used as parameter for the wake up call. Can I send to sleep and wake up a work routine in the same way, too?

EDIT: I know tried it the same way, by passing `current` from within the workqueue routine to the next workqueue routine. As a second way I set up a `struct completion` and passed it to the next workqueue routine. Both worked. But I'm not sure if it works by chance or if it is correct.

Comment: `I want to defer work from within a work routine itself` - Just perform the work within a "work routine". Yes, there is no multithreading there, but this requirement has no other solution.

Comment: @Tsyvarev How about completions ([link](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-5-sect-4))? Would they also not work in this context?